# How to bulk edit canonical url's in SQL?

Tags: mysql, bulk, rel-canonical

I've been assigned to edit the canonical URL's (rel="canonical" found in the head)of about 600 posts on a client's site. Not all of the posts will use the same canonical url. Nor are these 301's or 302's. I'm told not to use a plugin because I would have to edit each post one at a time. These are the general steps I plan to take:

1. Make an appropriate back up of the mySQL db in phpMyAdmin.
2. Download a csv of the table containing the canonical url's (using phpMyAdmin export).
3. Make a new csv that uses the post id and the new canonical url's (and a bit more magic).
4. Import the new csv (in its corrected format using LibreOffice)through a plugin called Really Simple CSV, which will write the new url's to the database.

[This is the tutorial I'm following for these steps](https://www.shivarweb.com/8635/how-to-make-bulk-edits-to-content-in-wordpress/).

My questions are: Using phpMyAdmin, what table is used to currently store these url's, and what, exactly, are they called? And, has anyone done this sort of edit before?

The site is currently on WordPress 3.9.x (it's outside of our scope of work to update their site to a newer version.)

Help please!

Comment: By canonical URL I take it you mean the post slugs? It's almost as quick to use Quick Edit on the edit posts list in the admin as it is to edit a CSV and you don't have the pain of re-importing. All the CSV import plugins I tried for a project recently filled my database with extra tables that I didn't want too.

Comment: By canonical URL I mean the rel="canonical" found in the <head>. I'll edit this into the question above.

Comment: Ah. And do the posts have multiple real URLs on your site? Are you aiming for each post's Permalink and the canonical URL to match? If so, just setting new slugs should change both unless you have a plugin or theme code adjusting your rel canonical fields.

Comment: That would be too easy. What I have to do is change the rel="canonical" of www.site.com/category/story-about-something to www.site.com/category, or in some cases, www.site.com/projects/article-about-something/2 to www.site.com/projects/article-about-something

Comment: Since they are generated and not stored in the db you are going to have to use some kind of plugin. Yoast SEO does it and explains how here https://yoast.com/rel-canonical/  That page also suggests that what you're planning will hurt your SEO if I've understood your question.

Comment: Yoast was my initial choice, but requires WP 4.3. I was afraid that it may be generated and not stored in the DB, but wanted to confirm. As far as the SEO, I don't really know, it was the task assigned to me.

Comment: Are you in a position to add your own plugin to handle this? Are you familiar with exporting and importing data using phpmyadmin? If so I may have an answer but it'll have to wait till tomorrow as I'm not at a proper keyboard and should be asleep.

Comment: I think I'm just gonna have to do these one at a time for the sake of completing this project by the end of tonight/done by morning. It is something I'll keep looking into, as I'm sure we'll have more projects like this come our way, but tonight, it'll be much more efficient for me to just get them done than to create a new plugin, test it out and implement it. I've really appreciated your help!

Comment: I did not really understand what's the point of your whole exercise is. Why do you need _canonical_ URls? Do you have something like short links for the same content? Also you might want to explain and show some examples of how your old slugs look and where you need to transform them. Something that can be expressed with a Regex for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Down- and uploading CSVs is a tough one that forces you to make a bunch of steps manually which is prone to human error (and typos). My suggestion would be to do something that you can battletest locally in a local copy of your DB. Steps to follow:

1. Make a [database dump](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3933/385) using the `mysqldump` tool and use `scp` to [copy it to you locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15893822/376483)
2. Pull up a local WP install
3. Install [WP CLI](https://wp-cli.org/), the WP command line runner, locally
4. Run [`wp post update`](https://wp-cli.org/commands/post/update/) with the necessary commands locally
5. Test
6. Save your live database by renaming it
7. Upload your local copy of the database to your staging server
8. Test again
9. Make it your adjusted database your live database

Make sure that you have a time where no one fiddles with the database (take your site into maintenance mode!).

**Notes:**

**A)** In case you know the IP and port of your MySQL server, you can directly connect to it and pull the dump down to your machine without SSH-ing into remote:

```
mysqldump -P3306  -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -pYourPassWord databasename > ./dbdumps
```

Above will dump it in a subfolder of your current directory (`pwd`) named `dbdumps`. You should create it up front.

**B)** Assuming that you have *Bash* available (command line – sh will still be sufficient enough if you have not), you can use something like the following script. Add it to a file named `convert.sh`. Also assuming that you got *WP CLI* installed locally (or your Vagrant machine, Docker container, whatever dev environment you are using locally):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for id in $(wp post list --field=ID); 
do
    wp post update $id --post_name=foobar
done
```

As you did not detail that conversion for your posts slug, you will have to find a way to adjust `foobar` in above example. There are dozens of Stackoverflow answers on the [tag:bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) topic to help you. As usual [`sed` for the rescue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043344/search-and-replace-in-bash-using-regular-expressions) – there's nothing in the world that can not get fixed with *`awk` and `sed`* in a shell script.

You can run above shell script like the following from your terminal:

```
sh convert.sh
```

Just give it a try, fail, *rinse and repeat*.

I've written that mostly out of my head, so you will have to test it. Better make a copy of your local DB so you can trash it start again.